# Building graphs by networkx in tkinter with reading entries values

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, graph, networkx

I am trying to make my programm read matrix, which can be entered by user, and
build this graph somewhere in the root. So we can set number of points in our graph, then we can get empty matrix to insert our relations between points. After that I can submit my values and they are correct, but when I am trying to build graph there is always errors, fixing of which, creates new errors.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


class SimpleTableInput(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self._entry = {}
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                e = tk.Entry(self)
                e.grid(row=row, column=column, stick="nsew")
                e.insert(0, '0')
                self._entry[index] = e
        for column in range(self.columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)

    def get(self):
        result = []
        for row in range(self.rows):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                current_row.append(self._entry[index].get())
            result.append(current_row)
        self.matrix = np.array(result)
        return result


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, n):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, n, n)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")

    def on_submit(self):
        print(self.table.get())
        matrix = self.table.get()
        matrix = np.array(matrix)


def build_graph():
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
    plt.axis('off')
    G = nx.from_numpy_array(matrix)
    pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.bottom, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)


def create_matrix():
    n = int(e1.get())
    table = Example(root, n).pack(side="left")
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text="build_graph", command=build_graph)
    b2.pack(side='bottom')


root = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Number of points", command=create_matrix)
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.insert(0, '0')
b1.pack(side='right')
e1.pack(side='right')
matrix = []
root.mainloop()
```

I am new in tkinter so there is always errors, I cant fix correct, for example now I am getting:

**"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'"**

How can I fix it correct?

Or maybe I need to start with other GUI library in python for such tasks?

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error means you have standard list, not numpy's array or other array. List doesn't have method shape. Check what you have `type(your_object)` and convert it to array. Other GUI will not resolve this problem bacause it is NOT problem with GUI but with your data.  And always put FULL error message (starting at work Traceback) not only last line. There is information which line of code makes problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use list to create plot but it needs `np.array`.

In `build_graph` you have to get `table` from `Example` and convert to array

```
def build_graph():
    #global table 
    matrix = table.table.get()
    matrix = np.array(matrix)
```

(you use name `table` for instance of `Example` which has property table so you get `table.table` and it can be missleading)

There is other problems

`table` in `create_graph` is local variable so you can't access it outside this function. You need `global` to create global variable

```
def create_matrix():
    global table
```

Next you have common mistake

```
table = Example().pack()
```

It assign `None` to variable `table` because `pack()` returns `None`

```
table = Example()
table.pack()
```

There are small mistake with `side=Tk.bottom, fill=Tk.both` because you need `tk` instead of `Tk` or you can use strings `side="bottom", fill="both"`

Finally I get this graph.

[image]

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


class SimpleTableInput(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self._entry = {}
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                e = tk.Entry(self)
                e.grid(row=row, column=column, stick="nsew")
                e.insert(0, '0')
                self._entry[index] = e
        for column in range(self.columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)

    def get(self):
        result = []
        for row in range(self.rows):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                current_row.append(self._entry[index].get())
            result.append(current_row)
        self.matrix = np.array(result)
        return result


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, n):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, n, n)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")

    def on_submit(self):
        matrix = self.table.get()
        matrix = np.array(matrix)
        print(matrix)


def build_graph():
    #global table 
    matrix = table.table.get()
    matrix = np.array(matrix)

    f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
    plt.axis('off')

    G = nx.from_numpy_array(matrix)
    pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='bottom', fill='both', expand=1) # ERROR Tk.


def create_matrix():
    global table 

    n = int(e1.get())
    table = Example(root, n) # .pack(side="left") ERROR
    table.pack(side="left")
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Build Graph", command=build_graph)
    b2.pack(side='bottom')

root = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Number of points", command=create_matrix)
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.insert(0, '0')
b1.pack(side='right')
e1.pack(side='right')
matrix = []
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works,thank you. But this code buils only clicks( full graph), but it is already another problem)

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page - you will have more space to put code, full error message and description.